# Menus don't respond on mouse hover

Tags: macos, mouse

I'm using OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5. No matter what application I'm in, the menus don't respond to the mouse hovering over them. If I click a menu, then it responds with the appropriate action. I've rebooted and tried a different mouse. If I right click something and get the menu, when hovering over it, it doesn't respond to the mouse.

I'm pretty stumped on this one. Not even sure what to Google. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the system menus, they're not meant to do anything when you hover over them, you have to click.